# How to return a value like '0' when using count case and the column is null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this as part of a bigger query

```
   LEFT JOIN ( SELECT value, COUNT(CASE WHEN value = '1' THEN '1' END) AS sum )
```

The problem is that since this is a left join this value doesn't exists for all the results. I want that when the value doesn't exists to return a '0'. I've tried using something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT value, COUNT(CASE WHEN value = '1' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) AS sum )
```

But that still just returns null.
How can I return '0' if the value is null or rather when the value doesn't exists in the database for that result ? Why can't I use `ELSE` to return '0' if the value is not '1',  is it because the value is not different than '1' but instead it just doesn't exist ?

Thank you.

Comment: `CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE value END` or `COALESCE(value,0)`

Comment: select isnull(sum,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in the `LEFT JOIN`, because no row exists -- so the value is defaulted to `NULL`.

Instead, use `COALESCE()` when you reference the value:

```
select coalesce(sum, 0)
. . .
```